# Code completion, insert use operator (namespace) with right click on undefined class

Tags: phpstorm

When I type

```
class MyController extends Controller
```

and I forget to choose the class from code completion, and then PhpStorm show me "Undefined class Response"; there is no way to add it, after I have written, using right click on the word "Controller" to get this line inserted automatically?

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
```

Why I need delete "Controller", type again and select from the list of classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why I need delete "Controller", type again and select from the list of classes?

It's a wrong place to ask for explanation for your own actions.

---

In any case:

1. Place caret on that place where IDE tells you "Undefined class XXX"
2. Bring the Quick Fix / Intentions menu -- <kbd>Alt + Enter</kbd> or via light bulb icon
3. Choose the appropriate menu entry -- it will be `Import class`
4. If there will be more than one choice -- IDE will show you the list of classes to choose from

[image]